# How to add limit to Hibernate query annotation?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

I have this in Java Hibernate

```
@Query("SELECT dirPar FROM DirectiveParagraph dirPar, Directive dir  "
        + "WHERE dirPar.directive = dir "
        + "AND dir.txtDirCode = :txtDirCode ");

List<DirectiveParagraph> getByName(@Param("txtDirCode") String name, @Param("page") int page ,@Param("size") int size);
```

I want to retrieve with limit and size, same way like this

```
SELECT * FROM tblDirectiveParagraph where intDirectiveID = 1 limit 10,10;
```

How do I add limit to above @Query annotation

Answer (score 7):

You can try adding a Pageable parameter to your getByName method

```
    @Query("SELECT dirPar FROM DirectiveParagraph dirPar, Directive dir  "
    + "WHERE dirPar.directive = dir "
    + "AND dir.txtDirCode = :txtDirCode ");
    Page<DirectiveParagraph> getByName(@Param("txtDirCode") String name, Pageable page);
```

And here's a sample method call:

```
    public void someMethod(){
        PageRequest pageR = new PageRequest(10,10);
        Page<DirectiveParagraph> result = directiveParagraphRepository.getByName("txtDirCode",pageR);
        List<DirectiveParagraph> resultList = result.getContent();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Limit is not supported in HQL. To set the size, you would use setMaxResults. To set start point, you use setFirstResult.

```
Query q = session.createQuery("...");
q.setFirstResult(10);
q.setMaxResults(10);
```

If you don't want to do it that way, you would have to use createSQLQuery to write a native sql query instead of hql.

Comment: Op specifically asked about a case using the @Query annotation.